# UIWindow is appearing in Portrait in a Landscape only app

Tags: ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, uiwindow

```
- (UIWindow *)overlayWindow {
    if (!_overlayWindow) {
        _overlayWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [_overlayWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
        _overlayWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        _overlayWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        _overlayWindow.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

        [_overlayWindow addSubview:self.dimmer];

    }
    return _overlayWindow;
}
```

The frame is correct - 0, 0, 1024, 768.

The app only supports landscape, as confirmed by info.plist (Supported interface orientations (iPad) are landscape left and landscape right).

However, the new window appears at 0,0 on the iPad as if it were in portrait, and orientated at 90 degrees with respect to the rest of the app.

The window is presented like this:

```
[self.overlayWindow setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1];
self.overlayWindow.alpha = 1;
self.overlayWindow.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

What am I doing wrong? I simply want to create a new window and display it over the rest of the app and have it orientated like the app's main window.

Comment: Ru planning to add window or viewcontroller on top of main window

Comment: The window is added automatically via makeKeyAndVisible, right?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
- (UIWindow *)overlayWindow {
    if (!_overlayWindow) {
         _overlayWindow = [[UIWindow new];
         [_overlayWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
         _overlayWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
         _overlayWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
         _overlayWindow.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
         [_overlayWindow addSubview:self.dimmer];
    }

    return _overlayWindow;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a bit explanation saying what precisely is different and why does it help?